# Adapter not working inside asyncTask when notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i've got problem when trying to implement loadmore, exactly problem is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged inside AsyncTask. i trying to implement from this tuts https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore 
, this tuts try implementing using extend ListActivity in Class, but i'm using extend Fragment, anyway this code is working, but just data not updated when trying to get data from loadmore. i'm sorry if my language is bad :)

this is my class :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bye.swipetab.adapter.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;
import com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Tour extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = Tour.class.getSimpleName();

    View myView;
    private String[] values ;
    private static final String brand_value = "brand_value";
    // Array of strings...
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS"};

    // list with the data to show in the listview
    private LinkedList<String> mListItems;

    // The data to be displayed in the ListView
    private String[] mNames = { "Fabian", "Carlos", "Alex", "Andrea", "Karla",
            "Freddy", "Lazaro", "Hector", "Carolina", "Edwin", "Jhon",
            "Edelmira", "Andres" };


    // Declare Variables
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter vAdapter;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] flag;
    UnderlinePageIndicator mIndicator;

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tour_layout, null);


        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tour_header_layout, null);
        //View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tour_footer_layout, null);

        listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false); // header will not be clickable

        mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
        mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mNames));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.tour_listview, R.id.MobileArray, mNames);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                String brand_text = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MobileArray)).getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),brand_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), TourActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(brand_value, brand_text);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        population = new String[] {
                        "1,354,040,000",
                        "1,210,193,422",
                        "315,761,000",
                        "315,123,000",
                        "363,752,000" };

        flag = new int[] {
                R.drawable.offline_ide_4,
                R.drawable.offline_ide_1,
                R.drawable.offline_ide_2,
                R.drawable.offline_ide_3,
                R.drawable.offline_ide_5 };

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) myView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        vAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), rank, country, population, flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(vAdapter);

        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)myView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        indicator.setRadius(5 * density);
        //indicator.setBackgroundColor(0x7f0c006a);
        //indicator.setPageColor(R.color.black);
        //indicator.setFillColor(R.color.tab_bg_yellow_deep);
        //indicator.setStrokeColor(R.color.tab_bg_yellow_deep);
        //indicator.setStrokeWidth(2 * density);

        // set a listener to be invoked when the list reaches the end
        ((LoadMoreListView) listView)
                .setOnLoadMoreListener(new LoadMoreListView.OnLoadMoreListener() {
                    public void onLoadMore() {
                        // Do the work to load more items at the end of list
                        // here
                        new LoadDataTask().execute();
                    }
                });

        return myView;

    }

    private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (isCancelled()) {
                return null;
            }

            // Simulates a background task
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mobileArray.length; i++) {
                mListItems.add(mobileArray[i]);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mListItems.add("Added after load more");

            // We need notify the adapter that the data have been changed
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Call onLoadMoreComplete when the LoadMore task, has finished
            ((LoadMoreListView) listView).onLoadMoreComplete();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // Notify the loading more operation has finished
            ((LoadMoreListView) listView).onLoadMoreComplete();
        }
    }

}
```

please tell me why this is not working ?

Comment: According to your code it seems you must first call `onLoadMoreComplete` before `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: try calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in UI Thread like getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

Comment: still not working, on tuts, adapter not using global variable exactly like this getListAdapter(), because im using fragment im improvement using adapter globalvariable, but not working when trying update to listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*mListItems* is not used for anything.

*mNames* is the one linked to the adapter, not *mListItems* which you are filling in the AsyncTask, may be you should review that.

```
mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mNames));
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.tour_listview, R.id.MobileArray, mNames);
```

and then you do

```
        for (int i = 0; i < mobileArray.length; i++) {
            mListItems.add(mobileArray[i]);
        }
```

Comment: thank you, you give me enlightenment, i just changed first value in adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.tour_listview, R.id.MobileArray, mNames); TO adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.tour_listview, R.id.MobileArray, mListItems);
and added "listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" inside "onPostExecute", thanks it works ;)

Comment: glad to help, chears